# How to ban/report offensive players in Dota2?

Tags: dota-2

Playing Dota2 on low skill level I often face offensive comments and would like to do something with it. So I have few questions:

1. On gamepedia it is [written](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Report) that I can "give a negative feedback to others". But I can not find a way to do this. I see in the players profiles possibility to do positive feedback, but no negative feed back buttons like on the picture.
2. Is there a way to ban a person in a way that I will not see and hear his (hers) words in a chat?
3. Is there kind of black list, so I can add a person and never be put in the same game with him (her) in the future?

Comment: Open the player table on the left upper corner or with the "\" button on the keyboard and click the silence button nextto its name. You wont hear or read what he writes anymore and also if you play with him again he will still be silenced

Comment: @Elgert, where should I do it? In a random player dota profile I see only icon in the left upper corner and \ does nothing for me. and I do not see any button next to its name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To address the reporting part, this has to be done in-game. Press the offender's name in the scoreboard, then you'll be able to see "Report Player". Once you click that, you will be able to provide more information about your case.
2. In order to mute voice chat (mic), you can go under scoreboards again and press the sound button beside the player's name. However, if you want to mute the on-screen typing chat, you'll have to click "Mute chat" when you press enter.
3. No, you can't make a blacklist, because as Valve says, it goes agains the notion of matchmaking (mentioned above).

Comment: 3. You can now with Dota Plus

Answer (score 7):

Reporting and Silencing are both done while the game is being played. When the game ends your last chance is on the scoreboard. Right click on players name to report or click the silence button next to the name, remember always INGAME

Comment: Thanks. I found it. Also one can silence players via replays. Do you have any comments about black list?

Comment: There is no blacklist, goes against the notion of matchmaking, the silencing is the most close you can get to a blacklist

Answer (score 3):

With respect to your comment about blacklisting: there is no official feature, but muting someone persists past the game you muted them. This means if you are in the loading screen and see a player you've previously muted, you can simply disconnect then and there to avoid playing with them without suffering an abandon. This is called 'dodging', as some higher MMR players use this as a method to avoid playing with/against certain players.

Comment: Loading screean you mean screen with list of nicknames right before hero picking?

Comment: Argh that's horrible. I hope they fix it.